# SQL - Escape strings (ORACLE DB)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I'm struggling a little bit about this maybe someone sees something that i don't...

```
select 'BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('''SCHEMA'', ''TABLENAME_'' || to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'YYYY-MM')', cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;' from dual;
```

So the output should be:

```
BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'TABLENAME_2021_07'), cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;
```

Somehow I am not finding a way to escape the strings, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of having dynamic table names for each months you my consider partitioning

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic? It looks like you could construct the table name as `TABLENAME_2021_07` and then just pass it to dbms_stats.gather_table_stats as normal.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
select 'BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(''SCHEMA'', ''TABLENAME_' ||
       to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'YYYY-MM') ||
       ''', cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;'
from dual;
```

Comment: Hi, 

thx for your answer, the only issue here is the ' after TABLENAME with that query I get: 
'TABLENAME'_DATE
any idea?

Comment: @MladenNikolic . . . I moved the closing quote.

Answer (score 1):

Here the *reversed* approach  starting with the result and leading the result expression

- Start with the *result* string

  ```
  BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'TABLENAME_2021_07'), cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;
  ```
- Split it in the *static* and *dynamic* part

  ```
   BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'TABLENAME_
   2021_07                                                         <--- dynamic
   '), cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;
  ```
- enclose the  *static* parts with a q-quotes (so you need not to escape!), replace the  *dynamic* part with the expression and concatente all parts with `||`

Add in a select query:

```
 select
       q'[BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'TABLENAME_]' ||
       to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'YYYY-MM') ||                                                     
       q'['), cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;]'
    from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the q-quoting mechanism, it makes it simpler (you don't have to escape single quotes):

```
SELECT q'[BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'TABLENAME_' || to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'YYYY_MM'), cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;]' result
  FROM DUAL;
```

which results in

```
BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'TABLENAME_' || to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'YYYY_MM'), cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;
```

---

Your statement is *long* so it is difficult to see it, so - here's a simplified example which shows how to do it:

```
SQL> select 'stats(''schema'')' old_result,
  2         q'[stats('schema')]' new_result
  3  from dual;

OLD_RESULT      NEW_RESULT
--------------- ---------------
stats('schema') stats('schema')

SQL>
```

- `q`
- followed by a single quote
- followed by bracket (use the one that isn't part of the string!)
- now, write your statement as you would if it weren't enclosed into single quotes
- end it with a closing bracket ...
- ... and a terminating single quote

Comment: Hi, 

thx for your answer, can I use multiple q-quoting mechanisms in a single select statement? since the trunc() function needs to calculate the actual date in a string it does not do that so I suppose I need to divide it from the string right?

Comment: There are 2 typos in code you posted (and I reused), here: `'YYYY-MM')'`: table name can't have a dash (should probably be underline), and the last single quote should be removed. As of your question: you don't have to use the mechanism multiple times (but you can). Though, if you fix what I just wrote (and fixed in the answer as well), it *might* work OK.

Comment: The challange here is to *not* "escape" the `||` concatenations in the q-string. Which of course works but produces a different result. I know it from own *hard* experience;)

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```sql
select 'BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(''SCHEMA'', ''TABLENAME_'
       || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY_MM')
       || ''', cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;'
from   dual;
```

I find it helps to format it so that static and dynamic parts are on different lines then you can write out the static strings and then double up all the quotes to escape them and put a leading and trailing quote for the start and end of the string literal.

or, if you want a q-quoted string literal:

```sql
select q'[BEGIN dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA', 'TABLENAME_]'
       || to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY_MM')
       || q'[', cascade => true, no_invalidate => false); END;]'
from   dual;
```

Just write out your static string and add `q'[` to the start and `]'` to the end.